# Table in Two Column - Linewidth

Tags: tabularx, two-column, textwidth, column-width

I would like to set the width of this table to textwidth or linewidth. Ho would I do that in this two column template?

Any idea?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=3cm}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip = 3pt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section.

Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. 

% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{caption}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}   % let LaTeX compute intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Notation\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Formelzeichen & Description 1\\
    Formelzeichen & Description 2\\
    Formelzeichen & Description 3\\
    Formelzeichen & Description 4\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Condition & Symbol & Formula\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    test & test & test\\
    test & test & test\\
    test & test & test\\
    test & test & test\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Objective & Symbol & Formula\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    test & test & test\\
    test & test & test\\
    test & test & test\\
    test & test & test\\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. 

Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. 

Here is a the text about the introduction.Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction. This section is the introduction section. Here is a the text about the introduction.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `strip`  environment from the `cuted` package, which is a single column environment in two-column mode.

Comment: By use `\begin{table*}` ... `\end{table*}`. Table will appear on the top of the next page. For midle of the page you need to consider @Bernard comment.

Comment: See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2colfloat